# Dynamically communicate with Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an simple game using soft keyboard where people play with characters. So I want to change the background color of keys during the game. I know that there are tones of tutorials and questions out there answering to changing background and  color of keys but my question is a bit different. Because I want to do it dynamically and I have had a hard time to figure out that how can I do it. I am using Android soft-keyboard but I don't know where and how can I add a listener to change the corresponding key's background. And how my game-engine sends this signal to the keyboard? Could you help me what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the appearance of the soft keyboard from your app will likely be impossible, especially on a per-key level as you describe.

The most feasible option would be to [create a custom keyboard specifically for your application.](https://ssaurel.medium.com/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289)

You could possibly get in touch with the developer of a keyboard app but it's unlikely they'd be willing to add a back door just for your game- and even if they were, your users would then be required to install that keyboard to play your game, which is not ideal.